# Sending data Arduino + Bluetooth module HC-05

Tags: java, android, terminal, bluetooth, arduino

I have been working on a problem for quite a while.

I have an **Arduino UNO**(Baud rate: 9600) and **HC-05 Bluetooth Module**(Baud rate: 38400).

I connect the **HC-05** to **Arduino** in following sequence

```
HC-05             Arduino UNO
-----             -----------
RX       -->      Pin 11
TX       -->      Pin 10
+5v      -->      +5v
GND      -->      GND
```

I have written the following **code**

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial BTSerial(10, 11); // RX | TX
String character;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(9, OUTPUT);  // this pin will pull the HC-05 pin 34 (key pin) HIGH to switch module to AT mode
  digitalWrite(9, HIGH);
  Serial.println("Enter AT commands:");
  BTSerial.begin(38400);  // HC-05 default speed in AT command more
  BTSerial.println("Bluetooth");
}

void loop()
{
  if (BTSerial.available()) {
    character = BTSerial.read();
    Serial.println(character);
    BTSerial.flush();
  }
}
```

**The problem is: I am able to recieve the message (from arduino to android), But i am unable to transmit the message (from Android to Arduino).**

**If i transmit, nothing appears in the Arduino software console.**

For sending message to bluetooth, i use [Bluetooth terminal app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ptah.apps.bluetoothterminal&hl=en) for android.

Please Help.

Thankyou

Comment: It seems **obvious** that you are using the **wrong pin**: `pinMode(9, OUTPUT);` when it should be **11**. Or redo your connection and connect the HC-05 RX pin to Arduino Pin **9**.

Comment: @ModularSynth  I have changed the code to pinMode(11, OUTPUT), now when i am executing AT command, i am getting -1 as OUTPUT. Why?

Comment: Now I don't recall the schematics. Make sure that RX goes to TX and TX goes to RX. If you connect RX to RX and TX to TX, it won't work.